Solving 1st order PDE including convolution
I'm studying Van Kampen's "Stochastic processes in physics and chemistry" and stuck to some exercise (p.78):
That is, solving
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial P(y, t)}{\partial t}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} P\left(y^{\prime}, t\right) P\left(y-y^{\prime}, t\right) \mathrm{d} y^{\prime}-P(y, t)
\end{equation}
with initial condition
\begin{equation}
P\left(y, t_0\right)=\delta\left(y-y_0\right)
\end{equation}
I tried Laplace transform.
But for unilateral Laplace transform, convolution term doesn't work well.
For Bilateral Laplace Transform,
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial\tilde{P}}{\partial t}=\tilde{P}^2-\tilde{P}, \qquad \tilde{P}(s, t):=\mathcal{B}_y\left[P(y, t)\right]
\end{equation}
while initial condition becomes
\begin{equation}
\tilde{P}(s,t_0)=e^{y_0s}.
\end{equation}
Then Laplace-form solution is
\begin{equation}
\tilde{P}=\frac{1}{1-e^{t-t_0}(1-e^{y_0s})}
\end{equation}
I tried to inverse this formular, but
Periodic Summation
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems)
of unilateral case can't be applied, since the geometric sum can't be defined for integral whose both limit is integral.
How can I solve this equation?

Fourier in $y$?

Perhaps this characterization of the convolution of two delta functions can help to simplify the RHS

"For Bilateral Laplace Transform, Periodic Summation of unilateral case can't be applied." Could you explain why this remark is relevant for the solution of the problem?

@Gonçalo Thanks for comment. I edit the question.

The Fourier transform works a little simpler here, since you can write down the result as an inverse Fourier transform. But it is not especially obvious whether said inverse transform can be expressed in closed form.

@Semiclassical Ok, I'll try Fourier first, and report later.
